# Can the Jacquard loom be considered stateless?

Tags: history, state

Can the [Jacquard loom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacquard_loom), pictured below complete with its chains of paper cards
[image: Jacquard loom]

be considered stateless? As far as I can tell [I can tell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacquard_loom#Principles_of_operation), each operation is not dependant on the previous. Or did it have any concept of branching and/or looping?

Comment: There is one endless loop.  Its a `10 print "hello"; 20 print "world"; 30 goto 10;` Thats it.  Two commands: "print this line" (a row in the fabric) and "goto start". Reading the Wikipedia page goes a ways to this understanding.

Comment: Actually it's probably closer to `10 PRINT whatever you see in the current row of the card; 20 advance to the next row on the card; 30 GOTO 10;` but yes, it appears to be stateless, in the sense that it doesn't remember anything from one loop to the next.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the loom is stateful in that it knows what the current card is. (So it keeps track of line # according to the analogies from comments.) The program, however, is stateless, because each card just weaves a line with no knowledge of what came before or after. So loom: No. "Program": Yes. :)

Moreover, the loom is mutable, because it's always changing the state of "current card" rather than spawning a brand new loom where the next card is in front.

Moreover, both the loom and cards have side-effects, because they result in a new line of weaving in the rug or tapestry or whatever they're making.

I would say the loom is Object-Oriented, because it receives a message in the form of a chain of cards, and then iterates through that message to produce side-effects. So there. :P

Comment: Really love this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well although the loom's engine contains internal state -- the current card -- this state is not accessible to the "program". Therefore from the point of view of the operator, the loom is stateless. Running a program through the loom does not depend on previous programs or subsequent programs.

The cards you feed to the loom can not change, making them immutable. They describe the line to be woven, rather than issuing a command. Therefore they are declarative.

The cards do have side-effects, so they are unsafe.

I would say that the loom is therefore functional, although not purely functional. It receives a parameter in the form of a chain of cards, and performs a classic comprehension on those cards, although this evaluation does have side effects.

The Real question, though, is does the Jacquard loom have a Buddha nature?

;)